# Show uploaded Images on page as grid or list of images

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am uploading multiple Images from my Reactjs application. So I have a page which has a button to open upload form. All the Images are uploaded to azure blob storage. I want to show all these images on this page after the upload completes. As all the images will be of different aspect ratios, How should I show it on this page as grid or list of images? 
[image]

Comment: 'will be of different aspect ratios' - what do you mean? different width and height?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can display the images as a list for mobiles.
If you want to create more responsive layout - you can try the pinterest's one.

Here is the lib ([Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)) which can help you to work it out.

[Here](http://www.kristianhammerstad.com/) is an outstanding example implemented with it.

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is when state changes the grid-list doesn't gets update.

Comment: woow my crystal ball can't help

Comment: what do you mean - render () doesn't run or what?

Comment: render runs. But look at the icon on the right most of screenshot attached, one on the right of three images. That is the new image added, not showing as like other three.